# How to mixin some class methods and some instance methods from a module in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, mixins

I have a module and would like to mixin some methods as class methods and some as instance methods.

For example:

```
module Foo
  def self.class_method
  end

  def instance_method
  end
end

class Bar
  include Foo
end
```

Usage:

```
Bar.class_method
Bar.new.instance_method
```

Is it possible to do this in Ruby?

If not, is it possible to define which methods are class methods and which are instance methods within the Bar class?

I ***don't*** want the same method defined as both a class and instance method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This pattern is very common in Ruby. So common, in fact, that [ActiveSupport::Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) abstracts it a bit.

Your typical implementation looks like this:

```
module Foo
  def self.included(other_mod)
    other_mod.extend ClassMethods
  end

  def instance_method
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def class_method
    end
  end
end

class Bar
  include Foo
end
```

You can't accomplish this easily as you describe without somehow splitting the included module into multiple pieces, though, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the note about splitting the included module into multiple pieces. I was wondering about that too.

Answer (score 3):

You can, but not quite like that. This is a common pattern for including both instance and class methods in one module.

```
module Foo
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  def instance_method
    puts 'instance'
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def class_method
      puts 'class'
    end
  end
end

class Bar
  include Foo
end

bar = Bar.new
Bar.class_method    #=> 'class'
bar.instance_method #=> 'instance'
```

Answer (score 2):

You are close. You probably noticed that the instance method works fine. The problem with the class method is that `self => Foo` when it's defined, so it does not respond to `Bar`. If you add the line `puts "I'm a module method"` in `self.class_method`, you will find

```
Foo.class_method => "I'm a module method"
```

Here's an easy way to accomplish what you want to do:

```
module Foo_class
  attr_accessor :cat
  def class_method
    puts "I'm a class method" 
  end
end

module Foo_instance
  def instance_method
    puts "I'm an instance method" 
  end
end

class Bar
  extend Foo_class
  include Foo_instance
end

Bar.class_method        #=> I'm a class method
Bar.cat = "meow"
Bar.cat                 #=> "meow"
Bar.new.instance_method #=> I'm an instance method
```

I added a class instance variable, `@cat`, and an accessor for it, just to show how easy that is to do.

[Object#extend](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-extend) is great, because you can just add instance variables and methods to a module, just as you would do with [Object#include](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Module.html#method-i-include) to mixin instance variables and methods, and `extend` mixes them in as class instance variables and class methods.  You can also do this:

```
bar = Bar.new
bar.extend Foo_class
```

to have the instance variables and methods in `Foo_class` apply to the instance `bar`.